# Perform lowpass filter by hand

Tags: lowpass-filter, amplitude

I've done research and could not find any resources on this topic.

I have *message signal* composed of more sinusoids. Then I preform **amplitude modulation**, that is multiply that signal with higher frequency carrier signal, and obtain *modulated signal*. Then to demodulate that signal, I multiply the signal with same carrier signal, and obtain *demodulated version of signal*. Then I should pass the signal through low pass filter, to obtain signal identical to message signal.

If I do this by matlab using `fdesing.lowpass` it is fine I get good output, but how to do this low pass filter **by hand on paper**, if I just ignore frequencies higher than the maximum frequency in message signal I don't get same amplitudes.

I multiply signals by using inverse Euler formula for $\cos$.

Any link or help would be appreciated.

If I didn't make myself clear, let me now and I will try to write an example (which I omit for now because I don't see here any latex support for writing mathematical equations).

Comment: Latex support is enabled. Write away !

Answer (score 1):

> how to do this low pass filter by hand on paper?

You can use very simple low pass filter - [Moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average). Filter is quite simple - it is sum of **N** sample of signal divided by **N**. If length of filter will be equal to   period of carrier signal then performance of this filter will be good.